# Does the number or size of objects in an AWS S3 bucket have any performance implications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an AWS S3 bucket that is used for storing a number of files, about 50000 a day and about 5-10GB.

Currently we've got lifecycle rules to clear the files out after 2 days.  We need to keep these files for longer now (1 year).  The names are unique (start with GUID) and we're comfortable with the cost implications.

The question I have is whether insert or retrieval performance will be affected at all?

We don't list the contents of the bucket (obviously that would be slower).  The AWS documentation is vague but seems to imply that there will be no change but I wonder if anyone has any real world observations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience, I don't believe there will be any implications, as long as you are not listing the contents of the bucket in order to find the object that you want (and you said you are not).

If you already know the object key when you are about to GET it, then there should be zero performance implications.

Answer (score 0):

There will be no implications for performance of write or read.

These actions are queued as a background job and executed over time rather than happening immediately at the expiry time.

Remember your S3 bucket is distributed across a large pool of nodes that are shared in the region, therefore performance issues would affect many partners.

The delete actions do not count towards your quotas either.